# Sensor size of webcam

Tags: matlab, webcam, sensors

Using the calibration methods (Matlab or OpenCV), one can find the focal length of a webcam. I am wondering if there is anyway to measure the sensor size of a webcam as well?

Thanks

Comment: The simple way to measure this is to open up the camera and use a ruler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is `pixel size * resolution`

resolution is nothing but image `width * height` in pixels

in general pixel size is written at the specs of the camera; if you dont know, then [pinhole camera model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model)

```
f / (distance to object in mm) = (object length in pixels) * (pixel size in mm) / (object length in mm)
```

may help you calculate that. you should use an object with known size and at a precise distance to use the formula.

Comment: f / (distance to object in mm) = (object length in pixels) * (pixel size in mm) / (object length in mm)

Shouldn't it be 

f / (distance to object in mm) = (image length in pixels) * (pixel size in mm) / (object length in mm)

Anyway, the word "length" you used is little confusing, height of the object might be more appropriate